# How to Model the following constraints in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, clpfd

For simplicity let's assume that `f` is a binary relation over the domain `{1,2,3}x{1,2,3,4}`. I want to model the following constraints.

```
f(1,2) ∨ f(1,3)
¬f(1,4) ∧ ¬f(4,1)
∀x.∃y.f(x,y)
∀x.(f(1,x) => f(x,1))
```

Then I want to answer the following queries: `f(1,1)?`, `f(1,2)?`, ...

Each query should result in 1 if `f(x,y)` is true in all possible worlds, 0 if `f(x,y)` is false in all possible worlds, and unknown if `f(x,y)` can sometimes be true and sometimes false.